# Windows 10 mobile widelivetile not updating?

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am facing a problem in updating wide live tile while switching from Square Tile to Wide Tile  in windows universal app development. It is working fine in Windows surface and Desktop but not on the phone.  It is not  updating  Wide tile could someone please help me?

By default Wide Tile is working fine for us but when we change it from Square Tile to  wide tile it is not working in emulator.

Here is our total Sample code:

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
             TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
var _tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText03);
            var tileImage = _tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement;
            tileImage.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png");
            var tileText = _tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
         (tileText[0] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "xyz";
            (tileText[1] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "ABC";
            (tileText[2] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "EFGH";
            (tileText[3] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "IJKL";
            var tileNotification = new TileNotification(_tileXml);
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);

            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150PeekImageAndText02);
          var  tileText1 = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            (tileText1[0] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText ="xyz";
            (tileText1[1] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "ABC";
            (tileText1[2] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "EFGH";
            (tileText1[3] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText ="IJKL";
            (tileText1[4] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement).InnerText = "Sample App";
             var  tileImage = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement;
        tileImage1.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Wide310x150Logo.Scale-100.png");//Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(new TileNotification(tileXml));
```

Thanks,

Madhu.

Comment: I have fixed a few English issues and marked up your code.  Four spaces are required to kick it into code mode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you better use [NotificationsExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn642158(v=win.10).aspx) instead of using xml pattern, which is pretty easier to use.

Then, your code has an issue. By using the official library `NotificationsExtensions` , the code to update tile should like this:

```
                //small
                var smallTileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare71x71Image();
                smallTileContent.Image.Src = "ms-appdata:///local/" + smallName;

                //medium
                var mediumTileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare150x150Image();
                mediumTileContent.RequireSquare71x71Content = true;
                mediumTileContent.Square71x71Content = smallTileContent;
                mediumTileContent.Image.Src = "ms-appdata:///local/" + middleName;
                mediumTileContent.Branding = TileBranding.Logo;

                //wide
                var wideTileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWide310x150Image();
                wideTileContent.RequireSquare150x150Content = true;
                wideTileContent.Square150x150Content = mediumTileContent;
                wideTileContent.Image.Src = "ms-appdata:///local/" + wideName;
                wideTileContent.Branding = TileBranding.Logo;

                var largeTileContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare310x310Image();
                largeTileContent.RequireWide310x150Content = true;
                largeTileContent.Wide310x150Content = wideTileContent;
                largeTileContent.Image.Src = "ms-appdata:///local/" + largeName;
                largeTileContent.Branding = TileBranding.Logo;

                //Enable notification queue
                TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);

                var notification = largeTileContent.CreateNotification();
                TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
```